# Данные с формы на реакцию статьи не передаются

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Реакция на статью!</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="input.php" method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="positive">Позитив
    <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="neutral">Нейтрал
    <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="negative">Негатив
</form>
</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    echo 'Спасибо за заполнение формы.<br>';

    if (isset($_POST['radiobutton']))
    {
        echo '<p>Реакция на статью была : ';
        if ($_POST['radiobutton']==="positive") echo "<b>Позитивной</b>";
        if ($_POST['radiobutton']==="neutral") echo "<b>Нейтральной</b>";
        if ($_POST['radiobutton']==="negative") echo "<b>Негативной</b>";
        echo '</p>';
    }
    else echo '<p>Реакция на статью не была выбрана</p>';

?>

</body>
</html>

Почему эти файлы не видят друг друга? Спасибо
```

Comment: потому что нет события отправки формы? где submit? обработка формы запускается после сабмита формы. вам нужно сменить тип с radiobutton на submit. и submit стилизировать под radiobutton. тогда все заработает.

Comment: Спасибо, Николай, заработало!

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы передать результат формы в самой форме должен быть submit-button. В вашем случае необходимо либо добавить `<input type="submit">` к форме и привязываться к ее нажатию. Или же переделать все `<input type="radio">` на `<input type="submit">` после чего стилизовать submit под radio. Выбор варианта за вами. Оба варианта имеют место быть.